# Who is this tsum tsum?

Tags: character-identification, disney

I went round to my friends' house earlier and they had just finished a Tsum Tsum Disney jigsaw puzzle. We were able to work out most of the characters, but there was one we couldn't work out.

Can anyone tell us who the black and white striped character is? The character appears four times (see freehand red circles), but can be seen most prominently 2nd row from  bottom, 8 characters in, just above Tigger. Despite the colour scheme, we don't think it's Jack from *Nightmare before Christmas* as he is elsewhere in the puzzle. For reference, the puzzle is "Disney Tsum Tsum Impossible Puzzle".

[image: Tsum Tsum puzzle with character circled]
[image: A close-up of the mystery character]

Comment: I don't see it on the list: https://www.tsumtsumcentral.com/PlushCharacterList.aspx

Comment: I’m going to go with an empty chair.  There are a few of them.

Comment: Actually I think that Jafar may be the character that (starting from the bottom left) is four right and three up... which it does look like the puzzle has multiples of some characters because right next to Jafar is Jasmine's dad, but then he is also about the same distance in from the left about half way up the puzzle below Mickey... I know that doesn't help you identify the one you are looking for but...

Comment: @Odin1806 it seems each character appears 4 times spaced throughout the puzzle.

Comment: Is it the really tall hat of the guy you can see sitting in front of the one circled on the right? Is there a character with a hat like that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This character is Jack Skellington's buttocks.

The proof is in the puzzle [*70 Piece Jigsaw Puzzle Prism Art Petit Disney "Tsum Tsum" - The Buttocks*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0132I3PIU) which shows the backside of many of your favorite Disney characters in tsum tsum form:

[image]

Here is what Jack looks like as a plushie:

[image]

Jack Skellington's buttocks was also featured in the puzzle [*70 Piece Jigsaw Puzzle Prism Art Petit Disney "Tsum Tsum" - A Lot 2*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0132I3PUS). Buttocks of other characters were featured in the puzzle [*70 Piece Jigsaw Puzzle Prism Art Petit Disney Tsum Tsum Girls*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UF4LO24), [*Disney Tsum Tsum 1000 pieces Jigsaw Puzzle* ("So cute! Tsum Tsum madness")](https://perfectfit.sg/products/tsum-tsum-jigsaw-puzzle-1) and [*Jigsaw Puzzles 1000 Pieces "Tsum Tsum" / Disney / Toy & Puzzle*](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Jigsaw-Puzzles-1000-Pieces-Tsum-Tsum-Disney-Toy-Puzzle-/401111577319).

Comment: Thanks! So strange that they have one random back end of a character!

Comment: "*This character is Jack Skellington's buttocks*" - I love being on a site where this is a perfectly valid way to start an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I contacted the company (Clementoni) that produced this jigsaw and are responsible for the artwork.

I am informed that the image shows the back of Jack Skellington from "A Nightmare Before Christmas".

> Thank you for your kind e-mail. We kindly inform you that **the subject marked is the back of Jack Skeleton** [sic].

I have followed up with a question about why his back (and no-one elses) was chosen and will update accordingly.

Comment: must be a rights thing - both good answers (yours and the accepted)

Comment: @NKCampbell - Possibly. Either that or the artist thought he was being funny

Comment: also - fwiw - @FuzzyBoots, in a now deleted answer (that some people may still see) indicated Alpha - the Tsum Tsum he pointed out is Malificent in dragon form - you can see the horns have the characteristic white lines

Comment: Clementoni is an Italian company, and in the Italian dub of _"Nightmare before Christmas"_ the protagonist is named [_Jack *Skeletron*_](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Skeletron); so, while there is a small typo, it is not a completely misspellt "Skellington".

Comment: ... and of course I _had_ to misspell "misspelt" ..

Comment: @NKCampbell Note that Jack Skellington tsum-tsum-ified face _is_ in the picture (5th row from the bottom, 6th face from the right), so I think we can exclude copyright matters.

Comment: @NKCampbell and in (al least) other 3 places too, one of which just above his red-circled backside.

Comment: so it is - even stranger now!